# How to Automatically Align the First Letter of a Name with the First Letter of the Person's Title Beneath

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Consider

```
\documentclass{letter}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{flushleft}
December 20, 1883
\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushright}
James Joseph Sylvester \\
Savilian Chair of Geometry, Oxford
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

which suggests the beginning and end of a letter:

[image]

I would like to be able to automatically (not by trial and error) align, in this case, the *J* in *James* with the *S* in *Savilian* in a way that can be easily adapted to all future such purposes. (I am using the `\flushright` command here only for the purpose of the illustration.)

Remark: The purpose of this request is not how to typeset standard letters, but rather to properly format the authors' names of Introductions, Prefaces, and the like in books; and so, I am not looking for a standard template.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the content you want to align in a structure that supports that. This could eithe be a `minipage`, or a `tabular`. I use the latter with a singular `l`eft-aligned column below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{flushleft}
  December 20, 1883
\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushright}
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}}
    James Joseph Sylvester \\
    Savilian Chair of Geometry, Oxford
  \end{tabular}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this most helpful answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a stack.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\strutlongstacks{T}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{flushleft}
December 20, 1883
\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushright}
\Longstack[l]{James Joseph Sylvester \\
Savilian Chair of Geometry, Oxford}
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you kindly for this answer.  If there had not been another very good answer posted before it, I am quite sure I would be accepting it. I hope to learn more about your `\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}` package in the future.