# On Makeindex, Subentries, and Stackengine (and No Xindy)

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, stackengine, stack

It seems to be a well-known defect with `\makeindex` that the number of levels of an index entry is capped at three.

For example, if I run the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
\LARGE

``I love my subject.''\index{\textbf{James Joseph Sylvester}! After Woolwich and Charlottesville! Arrives at Baltimore}
%\index{\textbf{James Joseph Sylvester}! After Woolwich and Charlottesville! Arrives at Baltimore! Is paid in gold at Johns Hopkins}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Everything is fine; the Index being given as

[image]

However, if I replace `\index{\textbf{James Joseph Sylvester}! After Woolwich and Charlottesville! Arrives at Baltimore}` with

`\index{\textbf{James Joseph Sylvester}! After Woolwich and Charlottesville! Arrives at Baltimore! Is paid in gold at Johns Hopkins}`

then the Index disappears.

After viewing Steven B. Segeletes' answer to the question posed in [How to Automatically Align the First Letter of a Name with the First Letter of the Person's Title Beneath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622001/how-to-automatically-align-the-first-letter-of-a-name-with-the-first-letter-of-t), I have decided to posted this question:

QUESTION: Using `\makeindex` only (not xindy), is it possible to invoke the `stackengine` package in a clever way to accommodate a fourth level to an index entry; and if so, how may this be accomplished with a modification to the above code? If not with `stackengine`, is there another way without `xindy`?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess that would remove the actual indexing functionality, i.e., you would not be able to use another fourth-level entry elsewhere for the same third-level entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes there is always a level three entry before the (one or more) fake level 4 entries

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage %why
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
\LARGE

``I love my subject.''\index{\textbf{James Joseph Sylvester}! After Woolwich and Charlottesville! Arrives at Baltimore}
x\index{\textbf{James Joseph Sylvester}! After Woolwich and Charlottesville! Arrives at Baltimore,  Is paid in gold at Johns Hopkins@{\hspace*{15pt}Is paid in gold at Johns Hopkins}}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

---

or without comma for the level thre entry

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.ist}
delim_2 "\\nonumcheck "
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage %why
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options= -s \jobname.ist]
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\newcommand\nonum[1]{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\nonumcheck{\@ifnextchar\nonum{}{, }}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\LARGE

``I love my subject.''%
\index{\textbf{James Joseph Sylvester}! After Woolwich and Charlottesville! Arrives at Baltimore|nonum}
x%
\index{\textbf{James Joseph Sylvester}! After Woolwich and Charlottesville! Arrives at Baltimore,  Is paid in gold at Johns Hopkins@{\hspace*{15pt}Is paid in gold at Johns Hopkins}}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. May I inquire as to how one may prevent the comma and page number from being displayed on the "Arrives at Baltimore" line? Thank you.

Comment: @SamuelBowditch added requested version

Comment: Many thanks for the helpful update. Your update is most helpful. I have been trying to figure out when trying to mimic it in my actual document the equivalent to "arrives at Baltimore" disappears. My document must be causing a conflict with your workable code. Hopefully I can figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting your fine answer. I wanted to see if anyone would post an  answer from a stackengine approach as suggested in the title. Thank you again.