# Why This Code Eliminating Index Commas Works for \jobname.mst and Not for \jobname.ist

Tags: indexing, makeindex, filecontents, jobname, idxlayout

This post is an addendum to [How to Universally Remove the Comma from Each Index Entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630121/how-to-universally-remove-the-comma-from-each-index-entry).

In the link, I was looking for a universal way to remove the comma in each index entry.

Werner advised to include the following in the preamble:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.ist}
delim_1 " "
\end{filecontents*}

\makeindex[options=-s \jobname]
```

However, I was not able to make use of his answer because of installation problems on my end of a recent version of TexLive.

So, I figured I would attempt to modify his answer on my end in the hope of making use of his excellent approach.

The long and the short of it is this---eventually, I discovered that I could eliminate the `[overwrite]` (which was causing me a problem), change the `\makeindex[options=-s \jobname]` to simply `\makeindex`, and change the `jobname` extension from `ist` to `mst`, thus giving me the working code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst} 
delim_1 " "
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
%\makeindex[options=-s \jobname]
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\large

Some words.
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!02@\textbf{\color{red}{\textit{How to universally remove the comma?}}}}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!03@\textbf{\color{red}{\textit{How to universally remove the comma?}}}}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!04@\textbf{\color{red}{\textit{How to universally remove the comma?}}}}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!05@\textbf{\color{red}{\textit{How to universally remove the comma?}}}}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!06@\textbf{\color{red}{\textit{How to universally remove the comma?}}}}
    
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

with the desired Index:

[image]

QUESTION: Can anyone explain, with all the eliminations I made, why the code seems to work nicely when I use `\jobname.mst` (which Werner did not use) but abends miserably when I use `\jobname.ist`; more simply, relative to this problem, why `\jobname.mst` works and `\jobname.ist` doesn't?

Thank you.

Comment: the `-s` option to `makeindex` (and so to the `\makeindex` command with this package) has to be the full filename including extension so `-s \jobname.ist`  although personally I would not write it out every time get rid of the filecontents save it as `nocomma.ist`  and use `-s nocomma.ist`

Comment: as demonstrated here, as it turns out: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622091/1090

Comment: @David Carlisle Once again, many thanks for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-s` option to makeindex (and so to the `\makeindex` command with this package) has to be the full filename including extension so `-s \jobname.ist` although as the makeindex style does not depend on the specific tex file contents I would not write it out every time with `filecontents`. Save it as `nocomma.ist` and use `-s nocomma.ist`